# Run Netbeans maven project from command-line?

Tags: java, maven-2, command-line, netbeans

I've got a Maven project that runs perfectly inside Netbeans. How can I execute the application from the command-line (without Netbeans)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a plugin for that: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/

```
$ mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.App"
```

Assuming `com.mycompany.App` is you main class.

Comment: "-Dexec.mainClass needs to be replaced by -Dmain.class". Secondly the classpath is incorrectly set to "[...]\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin\..\boot\classworlds-1.1.jar". How do I correct this?

Comment: @Gili what is the problem with the classpath exactly? Can you update the question to show the obtained result (and how it differs from the expected one).

Comment: Marking as accepted because I no longer have the original project around and this answer seems correct (in theory, at least) :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Maven Exec Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) and its [`exec:java`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal as suggested is a first option. And the command suggested is correct, you have to specify `-Dexec.mainClass=VALUE` on the command line.

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.acme.Hello
```

Regarding your "classpath problem", well, you didn't describe it very clearly. What is your problem? What are your dependencies exactly? Just in case, there is a [`classpathScope`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#classpathScope) parameter allowing to define the scope of the classpath passed to the plugin. E.g.:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=com.acme.Hello
```

---

As an alternative to the above plugin, there is [MOP](http://mop.fusesource.org/). What is MOP?

> #### What is MOP?
>
> MOP  is a small utility for executing
>   Java programs which are stored as
>   artifacts like jars or bundles in a
>   Maven repository.
>
> MOP automatically deals with the
>   following for you
>
> - transitive dependencies
> - downloading artifacts from remote repositories and caching them locally
> - setting up your classpath