# How to run a maven created jar file using just the command line

Tags: java, maven, jar

I need some help trying to run the following maven project using the command line: 
https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture, the webcam-capture-qrcode example is the one I'm trying to run. I have it running using an the Eciplse IDE but need to move it over to just using the command line. I have the jar's created by maven.

I'm trying

```
java -classpath ./webcam-capture/target/webcam-capture-0.3.10-SNAPSHOT.jar  com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamQRCodeExample
```

but I keep getting the

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/sarxos/webcam/WebcamQRCodeExample
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamQRCodeExample
```

Answer (score 151):

Just use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you run you program:

```
mvn exec:java
```

Comment: Where should I add that? To the main project pom.xml?

Comment: @Oujk Yes, to the pom file

Comment: Which one? There is a pom.xml for almost every single directory in the project.

Comment: @Oujk Normally the one where your main class is in. In your case where you have com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamQRCode. Dependencies will be resolved by maven as usual.

Comment: where should execute this last mvn command? My system may not have maven installed. I need to distribute that jar for client without any more information.

Comment: Don't forget to specify your Main class in the <mainClass> tag.

Comment: This approach is normal fine. Except when you have lots of command line arguments to pass to the program this gets ridiculous.

Comment: But this does not make a runnable jar file

Answer (score 21):

**1st Step:** Add this content in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**2nd Step :** Execute this command line by line.

```
cd /go/to/myApp
mvn clean
mvn compile 
mvn package
java -cp target/myApp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar go.to.myApp.select.file.to.execute
```

Answer (score 18):

Use this command.

```
mvn package
```

to make the package jar file. Then, run this command.

```
java -cp target/artifactId-version-SNAPSHOT.jar package.Java-Main-File-Name
```

[after mvn package command. Target folder with classes, test classes, jar file and other resources folder and files will be created](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).

type your own artifactId, version and package and java main file.

Comment: i used this method and i'm getting 'could not find or load main' error. I ran this: java -cp TwitterMapReduce-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hadoop.TwitterJob
after doing mvn package. Any ideas why?

Comment: This alone will not work when the jar file has dependencies. The Maven exec plugin suggested by maba will _find_ the dependencies, while the Maven shade plugin suggested by Mohammed will _package_ them.

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure in your case. But as I know to run any jar file from cmd we can use following command:

Go up to the directory where your jar file is saved:

```
java -jar <jarfilename>.jar
```

But you can check following links. I hope it'll help you:

[Run Netbeans maven project from command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689020/run-netbeans-maven-project-from-command-line)

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html

Comment: That only works if there is manifest in the jar; in this case there is none. Thank you though.

Comment: A maven jar does not include dependencies