# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running on maven

Tags: java, maven, boofcv

I am running the following commands from [here](https://github.com/srisankethu/Cloak/tree/master/cloak)

`mvn package`

The package is compiling sucessfullly.

But when I am running

```
java -cp target/cloak-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.github.cloak.App
```

It is giving the following error

> Error: Unable to initialize main class com.github.cloak.App
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: boofcv/gui/image/ImagePanel

Am I compiling the wrong way?

EDIT: I am not using eclipse

UPDATE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52367511/5699915

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency) post?

Comment: Your class path should include all of your dependencies (unless you are using some bundling / fat jar so that all of your dependencies reside in a single jar). To create a folder with all of your dependencies use dependency:copy-dependencies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError on Maven dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568275/noclassdeffounderror-on-maven-dependency)

Answer (score 2):

use `mvn exec:java`

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

see this post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15872962/1484621

Answer (score 2):

One way is to create fat jar with all dependencies.Assembly plugin is the simplest, add these lines to pom.xml and repackage it.

```
 <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
            <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.github.cloak.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
            </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
```